# flutter dartのファイルがインポートできません。intelliJ環境

Tags: intellij-idea

下記のコードを実行しようとすると、ファイルがインポートできないというエラーが発生します。
flutter、dartへのパスは通しているのですが、他に設定が必要でしょうか。ご教授いただけると大変助かります。

【パス】
[image: flutter]
[image: dart]

【コード】

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

【エラー内容】

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'flutter' in 'package:flutter/material.dart'.
main.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'package:flutter/material.dart'
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
       ^
main.dart:7:16: Error: Type 'BuildContext' not found.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
main.dart:7:3: Error: Type 'Widget' not found.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ^^^^^^
main.dart:5:21: Error: Type 'StatelessWidget' not found.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
main.dart:3:16: Error: Method not found: 'runApp'.
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
               ^^^^^^
main.dart:7:16: Error: 'BuildContext' isn't a type.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
main.dart:12:18: Error: Method not found: 'Text'.
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
                 ^^^^
main.dart:11:17: Error: Method not found: 'AppBar'.
        appBar: AppBar(
                ^^^^^^
main.dart:15:18: Error: Method not found: 'Text'.
          child: Text('Hello World'),
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/182461

Comment: リンク有難うございます。リンク先で解決しました。

Comment: 解決してよかったです。SOは自己回答ができるのでご検討ください。

Answer (score 1):

解決案をteratailでいただきました。
https://teratail.com/questions/182461

> flutter packages get

を再実行すると解消しました。

参考：flutter公式ドキュメント
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#adding-a-package-dependency-to-an-app